# How do i turn of all other switches in a UITableview except the one i clicked

Tags: swift, xcode9, uiswitch

I have a tableView that has a UISwitch in it I am using notificationCenter to get the row of the UISwitch. How do I now use that info to turn off every other switch except the switch that I clicked?

```
func creatNotification()  {
    let switchNotification = Notification.Name("answer")

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(getSwitchRow),name:switchNotification, object:nil)

}
@objc func getSwitchRow(notification: NSNotification){
    rowNumber = notification.object as! Int
    print("dataView2, getSwitchRow, rowNumber:", rowNumber)
}  

@IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    var dataViewObject = DataView2()
    dataViewObject.creatNotification()
    let switchNotification = Notification.Name("answer")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: switchNotification, object: rowNumber)

    let switchNotification2 = Notification.Name("switch")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: switchNotification, object: answerSwitch.isOn)

    if(answerSwitch.isOn == true){

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define an attribute  : var previousSwitch: UISwitch?

Then the Selector :

```
@objc func setOn(sender: UISwitch,indexPath: IndexPath){
    if previousSwitch != nil {
        previousSwitch?.isOn = false
    }
    let sw = sender
    let isSetOn = sw.isOn
    if (isSetOn){
        print("on")
    }else{
        print("off")
    }
    previousSwitch = sw
}
```

and in Cell :

```
sw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setOn(sender:indexPath:)), for: .valueChanged)
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(sw)
```

Comment: sw as in the switches outlet? and were do you want to define the previous switch?

Comment: You can define in the current class to record the switch that was clicked last time, and the next time you click, you will cancel the switch from the previous record and let the current click get state.

Comment: so you mean where i run my tableView i need to define the previousClick? or do you mean from the cell class?

Comment: Where class can listens for switch.

Comment: But i need a notification center to get the indexPath of where i click so i have no selector that looks like the setOnFunc and where should that function get the indexPath from do you mean?

Comment: i understand Thx

Comment: You don't need notification, you can use the switch. SuperView gets the cell, and then tableview.indexpath (for:) to get the indexPath.